# why isn't my vector pushbacking even and odd numbers

Tags: c++

i tried to separate even and odd numbers using vectors from a array ==>
so i made a function that returns true is number is even and false for if number is odd
then i used an if else statement where if the function returns true then it pushbacks the value in a vector and if the function returns false then it pushbacks the value in another vector , finally i printed all the elements in the vector but the output does not show any element except it shows one in the odd vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool sort(int arr[] , int i){
    if(arr[i] %2 == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int *arr = new int[n];
    for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++){
        arr[i-1] = i;
    }
    vector <int> even , odd;
    int i=0 ;
    if(sort(arr , i)){
        even.push_back(arr[i]);
        sort(arr , i+1);
    }else{
        odd.push_back(arr[i]);
        sort(arr,i+1);
    }

    cout << "the even numbers are : " << endl;
    for(auto element:even){
        cout << element << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "the odd numbers are : " << endl;
    for(auto element:odd){
        cout << element << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `if (sort(arr, i)) ...` just once - if you want to call it for every element in `arr`, you'll need another `for`-loop around it.

Comment: If this isn't for a learning exercise, [`std::partition_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy) exists for this purpose.

Comment: Why `int *arr = new int[n];` when you know about `vector`?

Comment: `sort` is a pretty strange name for a function that doesn't sort anything. A good way to avoid problems is to choose your words carefully.

Comment: @molbdnilo , thank you , i'll keep this in mind from the next time

Answer (score 0):

As @TonyDelroy [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69908538/why-isnt-my-vector-pushbacking-even-and-odd-numbers#comment123577007_69908538), you have to make `for` loop around call to `sort(arr, i)`. Also first loop should go up to `i <= n` instead of `i < n`.

Your fixed working code below (see also `std::partition_copy` variant afterwards):

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/bhfoWjnsv)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool sort(int arr[] , int i){
    if(arr[i] %2 == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int *arr = new int[n];
    for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++){
        arr[i-1] = i;
    }
    vector <int> even , odd;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (sort(arr, i))
            even.push_back(arr[i]);
        else
            odd.push_back(arr[i]);

    cout << "the even numbers are : " << endl;
    for(auto element:even){
        cout << element << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "the odd numbers are : " << endl;
    for(auto element:odd){
        cout << element << " ";
    }
}
```

Input:

```
10
```

Output:

```
the even numbers are : 
2 4 6 8 10 
the odd numbers are : 
1 3 5 7 9
```

---

As @chris [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69908538/why-isnt-my-vector-pushbacking-even-and-odd-numbers#comment123577086_69908538) you can also use [std::partition_copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy) to implement your algorithm:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/cd7GM3KeK)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> arr(n), odd, even;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        arr[i - 1] = i;

    std::partition_copy(arr.cbegin(), arr.cend(),
        std::back_insert_iterator(odd), std::back_insert_iterator(even),
        [](auto const & x){ return (x & 1) == 1; });

    std::cout << "the even numbers are : " << std::endl;
    for (auto element: even)
        std::cout << element << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl << "the odd numbers are : " << std::endl;
    for (auto element: odd)
        std::cout << element << " ";
}
```

Input:

```
10
```

Output:

```
the even numbers are : 
2 4 6 8 10 
the odd numbers are : 
1 3 5 7 9
```

Comment: like you knoiw i am a beginner so i just got introduced to vectors and i wanted to do this , to be honest i didn't even understand the second programme you gave me , lol , i'll try to improve though .... thank you anyway ...

Comment: @NamrataMundhra Second program uses [std::partition_copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy) from standard library `std`, it is quite common in advanced C++ programs to use a lot of functions and classes from `std` library. But first program is very simple, basically I just fixed two mistakes in your code, just 3-4 lines changed compared to your code. So you should understand quite easily first program. Also if finally you think that my solution is correct then Accept it as correct, to do this go to top of my answer and to the left from it there is Check Mark to Accept

Answer (score 0):

You only push one element - the first.
Your partitioning code is equivalent to

```
if(sort(arr , 0)){
    even.push_back(arr[0]);
    sort(arr , 1);
}else{
    odd.push_back(arr[0]);
    sort(arr,1);
}
```

You need to loop over all the input numbers.

You can also simplify matters with a more generally useful evenness function that doesn't depend on an array:

```
bool is_even(int x) { return x % 2 == 0; }
```

and then there is no need to store all the inputs before processing them:

```
int main(){
    vector <int> even , odd;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        if (is_even(x)) {
            even.push_back(x);
        }
        else {
            odd.push_back(x);
        }
    }

    cout << "the even numbers are : " << endl;
    for (auto element:even){
        cout << element << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "the odd numbers are : " << endl;
    for (auto element:odd){
        cout << element << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: that was really helpful , i understood now , thanks dude !